# ItemsControl not showing items

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

It has been while since I worked with XAML on a regular basis and I am struggling with the basics.

I am trying to show items in an `ItemsControl` like so:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="800">

    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding ProfilePages.Count}"></TextBlock>

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProfilePages}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello World" Height="100" Width="200" Background="AliceBlue"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>   

</DockPanel>
```

The ViewModel is just as basic:

```
public class XtmProjectViewModel : NotifyingObject
{
    private ViewModelCollection<XtmProfilePageViewModel, XtmProfilePage> _profilePages;

    public ViewModelCollection<XtmProfilePageViewModel, XtmProfilePage> ProfilePages
    {
        get { return _profilePages; }

        set
        {
            _profilePages = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProfilePages);
        }
    }

    public ViewModelCollection<XtmSearchPageViewModel, XtmSearchPage> SearchPages { get; }

    public XtmProjectViewModel(XtmProject model)
    {
        ProfilePages = new ViewModelCollection<XtmProfilePageViewModel, XtmProfilePage>(model.ProfilePages, s => new XtmProfilePageViewModel(s));
        SearchPages = new ViewModelCollection<XtmSearchPageViewModel, XtmSearchPage>(model.SearchPages, s => new XtmSearchPageViewModel(s));
        ProfilePages.CollectionChanged += ProfilePages_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void ProfilePages_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProfilePages);
    }
}
```

`ViewModelCollection` is a custom type which synchs with the underlying collection of models automatically. I've used this for years in all types of scenarios with no problems.

However, in the view, the items don't show up and I get a weird behavior which I cannot explain:

- The text block bound to `ProfilePages.Count` works as expected, i.e. the number showing up is the number of items in the list.
- No binding errors
- The `CollectionChanged` event of the `ProfilePages`-collection is fired correctly
- Also adding a `RaisePropertyChanged`-event for the entire collection property in the `CollectionChanged` event handler doesn't change the behavior
- The get accessors of the `ProfilePages` property is called twice as expected in the previous sceanrio (firing `RaisePropertyChanged`)
- When I edit the XAML while debugging, sometimes items show up in the `ItemsControl` as expected. The list of items doesn't update afterwards, however

I cannot explain the behavior and have no idea, what the issue is. I have checked the common troubles (wrong definition of `ItemTemplate`, missing `CollectionChanged` event, layout bugs causing items to render invisibly, etc. with no success).

How can this behavior be explained?
How can it be fixed?

Comment: wondering if you are inserting the objects into ProfilePages *not* on the UI thread.

Comment: My first thought was the `ViewModelCollection` is not of type `IEnumerable`? But you said it is showing items sometimes. Have you tried using `CollectionViewSource` in XAML? You could also create temp collection and then assign it to your `ProfilePages` property.

Comment: @kenny That was ist, thank you!!

Comment: @kenny Feel free to post a reply! I'll delete mine and mark as solved!

Comment: @Marc you're welcome. Pushed it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On request of the OP, moving my comment to an answer, 15000 here we come ;)

wondering if you are inserting the objects into ProfilePages not on the UI thread.